# Using AsyncFunction constructor in Typescript

Tags: typescript, async-await

The following works fine in JavaScript, but gives a runtime error when using TypeScript:

```
let AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async () => { }).constructor

async function foo()
{
}

let myFunc =  new AsyncFunction("_this", "await foo()"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j4umkchw/

The error appears in Chrome 90 Dev Tools:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

What's odd is that I'm sure this *used* to work, but I don't know if it's a toolchain or browser change that's broken it.

Comment: Why not ```let myFunc = async () => await foot();``` ?

Comment: Because my "real" function is dynamically generated. This example just shows the problem.

Comment: Maybe it is relative with the Typescript version. I see changes on version 4.2 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#top-level-await

Comment: *Note there’s a subtlety: top-level await only works at the top level of a module, and files are only considered modules when TypeScript finds an import or an export. In some basic cases, you might need to write out export {} as some boilerplate to make sure of this.

Top level await may not work in all environments where you might expect at this point. Currently, you can only use top level await when the target compiler option is es2017 or above, and module is esnext or system. Support within several environments and bundlers may be limited or may require enabling experimental support.*

Comment: The top-level await changes are in 3.8. The issue seems to be that I'm just getting the wrong constructor.